# How to send data in edittext in a viewpager to sharedpreference on button click

Tags: android

i have a viewpager which consists of three xml files but the last xml file has an EditText and a Button.Now i want what ever the user types in the EditText to be saved into a shared preference on button click: These are my classes

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private   Context context;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {


    ModelObject mo = ModelObject.values()[position];
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(mo.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);

   Button butIntro = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.introStart);
   EditText= (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.introUsername);


    butIntro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    SharedPreferences sharepreff = getSharedPreferences("StartUpInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharepreff.edit();
    editor.putString("username",introUser.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
        }
    });
    collection.addView(layout);
    return layout;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ModelObject.values().length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    ModelObject customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position];
    return context.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
}
```

}

```
public class intro extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText introUser;
TextView username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, homeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
        ed.commit();
    }

    ViewPager intro =(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.introviewpager);
    intro.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));
     introUser= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.introUsername);

}

   public void newStart(View view){

       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, homeActivity.class);
      this.startActivity(intent1);
  }
  }
```

The app crashes each time i run it.Please can anyone help me figure out what i'm doing wrong here.Thanks

Comment: Could you pls add your errorcode? Moreover: your sdk should warn you that in this line "SharedPreferences sharepreff = getSharedPreferences("StartUpInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)"; in the adapter, SharedPreferences is unknown. Sharedpreferences are not accesable by a class. You have to call it via the context: context.getSharedPreferences()
Additonally: Classes always start with a uppercase letter "Intro"

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
com.example.michael79.phca E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.michael79.phca, PID: 1941
com.example.michael79.phca E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
com.example.michael79.phca E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.michael79.phca.CustomPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomPagerAdapter.java:35)
com.example.michael79.phca E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:870)

Comment: your button did not get initialized. Check if the xml reference is correct

Comment: yea it is.. i even changed it now buh its still crashing

Comment: whats the new error?

Comment: It is still displaying the same error

Comment: I dont kno if this "
   Button butIntro = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.introStart);" is the problem